# Jupyter Notebook Error local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm creating a Stop_word function in order to preprocessing my text data. "local variable 'text2' referenced before assignment" is my received error, working on Jupyter Notebook platform.

In detail,

- text is an array of text token
- list_stopwords = ['sinh viên', 'giảng viên']

I have debugged my code with an other platform, Pycharm and the result is fairly good (as I hope)

```
filename = './StopWord.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(filename,names=['word'])
list_stopwords = data['word']
def remove_stopword(text):
    pre_text = []
    for x in text:
        if x in list_stopwords:
            text2 = ' '.join(pre_text)
        else:
            pre_text.append(x)
    return text2
print(remove_stopword(tokenize_df[1]))
```

With

- tokenize_df[1] =['chất lượng',
  'môn học',
  'khá',
  'tốt',
  'giảng viên',
  'truyền đạt',
  'cho',
  'sinh viên',
  'nhiều',
  'kỹ năng',
  'có ích',
  'phòng',
  'máy',
  'đảm bảo',
  'về',
  'số lượng',
  'máy',
  'cho',
  'sinh viên']

I do wanna get a string "chất lượng môn học khá tốt truyền đạt cho nhiều kỹ năng có ích phòng máy đảm bảo về số lượng máy cho " as my input.
Thanks you a bunch for reading my question. Have a fabulous day!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your `remove_stopword()` function is returning `text2` but your code only ever sets `text2` if it finds a stopword. If it doesn't then the `else` always gets executed and `text2` never gets a value.

Postpone constructing `text2` until just before the `return` statement. You don't need to rebuild it every time you find a stopword. But you do need to build it at least once.

Comment: I'm greatly sorry for asking you further. I did a new one with only using `text2` , here's what I did : `for x in text: if x in list_stopwords: text2+="" else : text2+=x +""`  ` after all it will `return text2`. Nevertheless, the output did change anyway..

Comment: Finally, I've done with it; I created a new list for storage and it worked >.,,,,

Answer (score 0):

Your if then statement is causing problems. If the first part of your condition is met

```
if x in list_stopwords:
    text2 = ' '.join(pre_text)
```

And then you return text2, all is fine. However, if the second 'else' part of the condition comes into play, then text2 is not defined in the local namespace, and in cannot be returned.

```
else:
    pre_text.append(x)
return text2
```